# javascript addition issue despite using parseInt

Tags: javascript

I have been banging my head for some time now, please help with below. The value of first parseInt is 100 and second parseInt is 50. The above gives me value 1250, if I change totalq to 10, the above yields me 1050. That is, javascript is treating right hand side of calculation line as string, despite explicit request to treat it as an integer. Please help.

```
    totalq = 12;
<?php
    for($j=1;$j<2;$j++)
    {
    ?>
        totalq+= parseInt(removeCommas($("#team_quantitybondx<?php echo $j; ?>").html())) - parseInt($("#team_quantityredeembondx<?php echo $j; ?>").val());
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Try setting a radix, `parseInt(..., 10);`

Comment: this worked -> totalq = parseInt(totalq) + parseInt(removeCommas($("#team_quantitybondx<?php echo $j; ?>").html())) - parseInt($("#team_quantityredeembondx<?php echo $j; ?>").val());

Comment: @AakashGoel I added an answer, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var str1 = $("#team_quantitybondx<?php echo $j; ?>").html(),
    str2 = $("#team_quantityredeembondx<?php echo $j; ?>").val();

totalq = parseInt(totalq, 10);  //Just in case you had a string value here  
totalq +=  parseInt(removeCommas(str1), 10) - parseInt(removeCommas(str2), 10);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers